# Do ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION require a prominent disclosure message?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions, android-location

I see that the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission (which according to Google needs to be requested individually) requires a prominent disclosure (which according to Google needs to be also shown individually).

I also see that ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission requires prior ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions (which according to Google these need to be requested together).

My question is, would I also need to show a prominent disclosure message for these permissions?

Directions are a bit fuzzy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Those are categorised as "dangerous permissions". You need to ask the user at runtime for those permissions with a system UI dialog.